# Is it possible to use l3build to extract (working) lua source from dtx?

Tags: luatex, dtx, l3build

I have created one dtx containing both tex/latex/expl3 code **and** also lua code.

When running l3build doc on the dtx I obtain what I need with one problem which I don't see how to solve: the lua file begins and ends with LaTeX code which prevents its normal use.

If I was using a makefile I could manage to process the lua file to get rid of the tex code.

Is there a way to do something like that with l3build?

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extraction of code from a `.dtx` is carried out by DocStrip: `l3build` simply runs the appropriate job. So you need the right DocStrip setup in your `.ins` file. The most important thing is to set `\MetaPrefix`, which deals with comments, so

```latex
\def\MetaPrefix{--}
```

You *might* also want to adjust the preamble/postamble: in [`l3.ins`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/l3.ins) we do `\nopostamble` for example.